# Enable/Disable Status Bar Android

Tags: android, statusbar

I am developing an application in which i want to disable status bar on the user side and enable when used by admin. I'm successful in disabling status bar with the below code:

```
    WindowManager manager= ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |

                // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

                // Draws over status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

        localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
        localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        //  PrefUtils.setKioskModeActive(false, getApplicationContext());
        view = new customViewGroup(this);
        manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

But I'm not able to again enable to status bar.Is this possible to enable again with this code. or any other way to disable/enable status bar.
Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: try to invalidate option menu

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same from while. do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

@Kaifi you should remove same view from `WindowManager` as:

```
((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(YOUR_VIEW);
```

Or as:

```
manager.removeView(YOUR_VIEW);
```